# How to set the write concern for insert query with ReactiveMongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

How can I write the following query in ReactiveMongo.

```
db.products.insert(
   { item: "envelopes", qty : 100, type: "Clasp" },
   { writeConcern: { w: 2, wtimeout: 5000 } }
)
```

I have tried the like below.

```
db.products.insert(BSONDocument("item"->"envelopes","qty " -> 100,"type" -> "Clasp"))
```

Can you please suggest here how can I write the insert query with write concern in ReactiveMongo.

I have used writeConcern majority in DB connection like

```
val conOpts = MongoConnectionOptions(authMode = ScramSha1Authentication, authSource = Some(Configuration.dbName), writeConcern = WriteConcern.Default.copy(w = WriteConcern.Majority))
```